# Using variable in the name

Tags: c#, visual-c#-express-2010

Is it possible to use a variable to access 2 variables without naming another variable?

For example, to:

```
LOG.dig.CNLog = 7;
LOG.value.CNLog = 17;
```

I would like to use something like this

```
string a = "dig";
string b = "value";
LOG.[a].CNLog = 7;
LOG.[b].CNLog = 17;
```

It's possible to use this? If yes what is the correct format?

Thanks

Comment: Dictionary<string, int>

Comment: A blog entry on creating a dynamic dictionary: http://reyrahadian.wordpress.com/2012/02/01/creating-a-dynamic-dictionary-with-c-4-dynamic/

Comment: Check this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196991/get-property-value-from-string-using-reflection-in-c-sharp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196991/get-property-value-from-string-using-reflection-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @nullforce Given that the OP's problem derives from not knowing the property's name at compile time, then the dynamic dictionary doesn't solve his issue.

Comment: @nullforce What that blog gives which `ExpandoObject` doesn't have.? It shows how to reinvent `ExpandoObject`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Dictionary<string, int>`.  An example:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
dict.Add("test", 1);
var testVal = dict["test"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using a [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx).

A dictionary is a collection of keys and values. In your case you probably would like to use a `Dictionary<string, LogClass>` then you can have something like this:

Assuming `LogClass` is your class...

```
public class LogClass
{
    public int CNLog { get; set; }
}

string a = "dig";
string b = "value";

dictionary[a].CNLog = 7;
dictionary[b].CNLog = 17;
```

But of course before doing that you would have to say what is the value that goes into `dictionary[var]`.

```
dictionary[a] = new LogClass();
```

That is how you would use it, hopefully you will be able to adapt this solution to your code.

And you can check out a video that explains step-by-step very slowly and clearly how to work with it on [Microsoft Virtual Academy: C# Fundamentas](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/Content/ViewContent.aspx?et=7684&m=7680&ct=27122) at 22:00.